# проблема с broadcom 43142

Tags: kali-linux

У меня ноутбук asus x550jk с BCM43142 и kali linux на флешке. При запуске Linux не видит wifi карту. Устанавливал драйвера как здесь https://wiki.debian.org/ru/wl но команда `# modprobe wl` выдает ошибку `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-kali1-amd64`. Что я делаю не так? Как заставить работать wifi?

Вот еще:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей 
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет linux-headers-amd64 самой новой версии (4.14+87+kali1).
Уже установлен пакет linux-image-amd64 самой новой версии (4.14+87+kali1).
Уже установлен пакет broadcom-sta-dkms самой новой версии (6.30.223.271-7).
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  chromium-common dissy libarmadillo7 libbind9-141 libboost-atomic1.62.0
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0
  libboost-serialization1.62.0 libboost-test1.62.0 libboost-timer1.62.0
  libcaribou-gtk-module libcaribou-gtk3-module libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1
  libcdio13 libcgal12 libdns190 libevent-2.0-5 libgom-1.0-common
  libhttp-parser2.1 libisc189 libisccc140 libisccfg144 liblwres141 libnetcdf11
  libntfs-3g872 libqcustomplot1.3 libqgis-core2.14.20 libqgis-gui2.14.20
  libqgis-networkanalysis2.14.20 libqgispython2.14.20 libqt5opengl5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqtwebkit4 libradare2-2.0 libre2-3 libsfcgal1
  libtesseract-data libtesseract3 libx265-130 libxerces-c3.1 python-brotli
  python-cssutils python-rsvg
Для их удаления используйте «apt autoremove».
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
root@kali:~# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
root@kali:~# modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-kali1-amd64
root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 4.13.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.13.10-1kali2 (2017-11-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел в чем причина. был установлен linux-headers не той версии (linux image был 4.14 и 4.13):

`root@kali:~# dpkg -s linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Package: linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-amd64
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 4328
Maintainer: Kali Developers <devel@kali.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux
Version: 4.13.10-1kali2
Depends: linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-common (= 4.13.10-1kali2), linux-kbuild-4.13, linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86
Description: Header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1-amd64
 This package provides the architecture-specific kernel header files for
 Linux kernel 4.13.0-kali1-amd64, generally used for building out-of-tree
 kernel modules.  These files are going to be installed into
 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-amd64, and can be used for building
 modules that load into the kernel provided by the
 linux-image-4.13.0-kali1-amd64 package.
Homepage: https://www.kernel.org/`

(до этого писало что не установлен).
Скачав [здесь](https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/) headers 4.13 и установив, я повторно ввел команду `modprobe wl` и все заработало.